# Dataframe.unstack() equivalent in numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am running a code that calculates the correlation (Pearson) between columns in a DataFrame and then unstacks it to build a graph on it.

However the pandas `dataframe.corr()` is quite slow atm (21 000 columns) and I saw that `numpy.corrcoef()` might be much faster as I don't have NaNs.

However I use `df.unstack()` on the correlation results and I couldn't find a numpy equivalent

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. Have a look into `pandas_profiling` https://pandas-profiling.github.io/pandas-profiling/examples/titanic/titanic_report.html

Comment: Wouldn’t reshape or flatten suffice?

Comment: @alec_djinn I don't see your point...

Comment: You can insert results of `numpy.corrcoef()` to pandas data frame as a quick workaround

Comment: @ArtyomAkselrod I didn't think about it, very good point

Comment: @Mayeulsgc The point is that there is a library doing the correlation plot of the database for you with a single line of code already.

Comment: I didn't look for the plot, I was looking to build graph of all features related to each other above a given correlation threshold

Comment: @Mayeulsgc that is exactly what the library does. Install it and try `df.profile_report()`